# Why do I need to manually input username when connecting to switch with a python script?

Tags: python-3.x, vbscript, secure-crt

I'm converting a VB script that connects to a switch through SecureCRT into Python3. The original script contains:

```
crt.Session.Connect " /SSH2 /L " & user & " /PASSWORD " & pass & " /P 22" & " /ACCEPTHOSTKEYS " & ip
```

This script runs this command and continues through the rest of code, automated as it should be.

In my version, I use the line:

```
crt.Session.Connect("SSH2/L %s /PASSWORD %s /P 22 /ACCEPTHOSTKEYS %s" % (user,pass,ip))
```

My script runs up until this point where CRT displays:

```
#Banner
Please enter login information for #ip.
Username:
```

And it hangs there. I can manually type in `user` and the script continues on as expected from that point. Interrupting the script shows that it is hanging on this line, presumably waiting for an input?
How do I ensure the script sends the username as part of the command instead of requiring the user's input?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, and it's embarrassingly obvious. The line in python should be

```
crt.Session.Connect("/SSH2 /L %s /PASSWORD %s /P 22 /ACCEPTHOSTKEYS %s" % (user,pw,ip))
```

instead of

```
crt.Session.Connect("SSH2/L %s /PASSWORD %s /P 22 /ACCEPTHOSTKEYS %s" % (user,pw,ip))
```